# How to make TwinCAT3 in Visual studio could be use word text select highlighted like "Word Highlight With Margin"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, highlight, twincat, st

I am installed the Word Highlight With Margin , but it looks like not works with TwinCAT 3 text editor (ST) , any other way I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

The text editor of twincat ST is not based on the text editor of Visual Studio. You can see this when you change the color settings to dark mode. The twincat editor does not change.

So it is not possible to use standard text editor plugins for Visual Studio inside the twincat ST editor as they plug into only the VS editor.

Answer (score 0):

Word highlight is a [feature to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrpDY.png) in TwinCAT 3.1.4026 (along with [dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6EOm.png)!).

Comment: Is that version released ? I can't find on beckhoff Website

Comment: @robinshion Not yet, as far as I know. It should be available this year, but the release date was not announced yet.